# jquery scroll down - showing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

hey I was watching some code over here, and i got a little problem..
the code is:

```
    $(window).scroll( function(){

    $('.hideme').each( function(i){

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottom_of_window < bottom_of_object ){

            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'},1500);

        }

    }); 

});
```

I set every div with class hideme

the problem is when i scroll down to the first div, the whole site is shwoing up, and not just the first div i scrolled to.
how i change the code so everytime i scroll specific div its using the effect and not just fading the whole site in first div.

Comment: Would you please edit your question.  I don't know what it means to "rich every div".  Your question is altogether confusing.

Comment: I eddited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is backwords.

```
if( bottom_of_window < bottom_of_object )
```

Should be

```
if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object )
```

### [demo](http://codepen.io/brigand/pen/ukhgb)

Comment: hey, I tried it but it is fading the div just when i get to the bottom . how i change it so when i just "entering" the div it fading ?

Comment: The bottom of the page?

Comment: no, the bottom of the div. and its not helping so much cuz you missing the whole point of the site.. I want to fade in the div in exact time i get to the top of him (scrolling down) and not just when i get to the bottom of him(the div), thanks !

Comment: @etomernud, okay, so change your definition of `bottom_of_object`.  You currently have it set to the the top of the div + the height of the div, a.k.a, the bottom.

Comment: I was just about to publish my result. yes it was kinda stupid self mistake, but thanks anyway for your direction!